# WebLogic job scheduling

Tags: oracle, servlets, weblogic, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to implement a WebLogic job scheduling example, to test my cluster capabilities of fail-over on scheduled tasks (to ensure that these tasks are executed on fail over scenario).

With this in mind, I've been following [this example](http://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/2009/04/a_simple_job_scheduler_example.html) and trying to configure everything accordingly. Here are the steps I've done so far:

1. Configured a cluster with 1 admin
   server (*AdminServer*) and 2 managed
   instances (*Noddy* and *Snoopy*);
2. Set up database tables (using Oracle
   XE): `ACTIVE` and `WEBLOGIC_TIMERS`;
3. Set up data source to access DB and
   associated it to the scheduling
   tasks under "Settings for cluster" >
   "Scheduling";
4. Implemented a job (`TimerListener`)
   and a *servlet* to initialize the job
   scheduling, as follows:

.

```
package timedexecution;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import commonj.timers.Timer;
import commonj.timers.TimerListener;
import commonj.timers.TimerManager;

public class TimerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected static void logMessage(String message, PrintWriter out){
        out.write("<p>"+ message +"</p>");
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        //
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head><title>TimerServlet</title></head>");
        //
        try {
            //
            logMessage("service() entering try block to intialize the timer from JNDI", out);
            //
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            TimerManager jobScheduler = (TimerManager)ic.lookup("weblogic.JobScheduler");
            //
            logMessage("jobScheduler reference " + jobScheduler, out);
            //
            jobScheduler.schedule(new ExampleTimerListener(), 0, 30*1000);            
            //
            logMessage("Timer scheduled!", out);
            //
            //execute this job every 30 seconds
            logMessage("service() started the timer", out);
            //
            logMessage("Started the timer - status:", out);
            //
        }
        catch (NamingException ne) {
            String msg = ne.getMessage();
            logMessage("Timer schedule failed!", out);
            logMessage(msg, out);
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            logMessage("service() error initializing timer manager with JNDI name weblogic.JobScheduler " + t,out);
        }
        //
        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.close();
    }


    private static class ExampleTimerListener implements Serializable, TimerListener {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8313912206357147939L;

        public void timerExpired(Timer timer) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
            System.out.println( "timerExpired() called at " + sdf.format( new Date() ) );
        }
    }

}
```

Then I executed the servlet to start the scheduling on the first managed instance (*Noddy* server), which returned as expected:

(Servlet *execution output*)

> service() entering try block to
>   intialize the timer from JNDI
>
> jobScheduler reference
>   weblogic.scheduler.TimerServiceImpl@43b4c7
>
> Timer scheduled!
>
> service() started the timer
>
> Started the timer - status:

Which resulted in the creation of 2 rows in my DB tables:

- `WEBLOGIC_TIMERS` table state after servlet execution:

  "EDIT"; "TIMER_ID"; "LISTENER"; "START_TIME"; "INTERVAL"; "TIMER_MANAGER_NAME"; "DOMAIN_NAME"; "CLUSTER_NAME";

  ""; "Noddy_1268653040156"; "[datatype]"; "1268653040156"; "30000"; "weblogic.JobScheduler"; "myCluster"; "Cluster"
- `ACTIVE` table state after servlet execution:

  "EDIT"; "SERVER"; "INSTANCE"; "DOMAINNAME"; "CLUSTERNAME"; "TIMEOUT";

  ""; "service.SINGLETON_MASTER"; "6382071947583985002/Noddy"; "QRENcluster"; "Cluster"; "10.03.15"

Although, the job is not executed as scheduled. It should print a message on the server's log output (`Noddy.out` file) with a timestamp, saying that the timer had expired. It doesn't. My log files state as follows:

*Admin server* log (`myCluster.log` file):

```
####<15/Mar/2010 10H45m GMT> <Warning> <Cluster> <test-ad> <Noddy> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1268649925727> <BEA-000192> <No currently living server was found that could host TimerMaster. The server will retry in a few seconds.>
```

*Noddy server* log
(`Noddy.out` file):

```
service() entering try block to intialize the timer from JNDI
jobScheduler reference weblogic.scheduler.TimerServiceImpl@43b4c7
Timer scheduled!
service() started the timer
Started the timer - status:
<15/Mar/2010 10H45m GMT> <Warning> <Cluster> <BEA-000192> <No currently living server was found that could host TimerMaster. The server will retry in a few seconds.>
```

(`Noddy.log` file):

```
####<15/Mar/2010 11H24m GMT> <Info> <Common> <test-ad> <Noddy> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1268652270128> <BEA-000628> <Created "1" resources for pool "TxDataSourceOracle", out of which "1" are available and "0" are unavailable.> 
####<15/Mar/2010 11H37m GMT> <Info> <Cluster> <test-ad> <Noddy> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1268653040226> <BEA-000182> <Job Scheduler created a job with ID Noddy_1268653040156 for TimerListener with description timedexecution.TimerServlet$ExampleTimerListener@2ce79a> 
####<15/Mar/2010 11H39m GMT> <Info> <JDBC> <test-ad> <Noddy> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1268653166307> <BEA-001128> <Connection for pool "TxDataSourceOracle" closed.>
```

Can anyone help me out discovering what's wrong with my configuration? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is Snoopy also running at this time? Have you tried firing the servlet from Snoopy- just a thought

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't change anything. I've tried to reboot the machine (that hosts the hole cluster, as it it a local configuration on a virtual machine) and all I've got was this difference on Noddy's LOG ("Noddy.log" file): «####<15/Mar/2010 14H53m GMT> <Info> <Cluster> <test-ad> <Noddy> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1268664789340> <BEA-000189> <The Singleton Service TimerMaster is now active on this server.>»

Comment: I can see you've got no reply on the Oracle forum either. but isnt this "The Singleton Service TimerMaster is now active on this server" a success message from the earlier?

Comment: @josek I don't think so, as I shut down all servers (admin and managed servers) and then deleted log files. This messages where logged after cluster restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned out to solve this problem by restarting the whole system and then starting WebLogic instances from the command line. In this perspective I managed to get this into working, with the output being sent to the command line.

I'd like to thank everyone who tried to help me solving this one.

Answer (score 1):

Also try to add the debug (JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dweblogic.debug.DebugSingletonServices=true -Dweblogic.JobScheduler=true)

For me, it was not enough to put it just in the server startup params via Console. I had to put in setDomainEnv.sh.